# Better Jason encoder for schemas automatically

Tags: json, encoding, elixir, schema, phoenix-framework

I got this warning

**warning: the Jason.Encoder protocol has already been consolidated, an implementation for Any has no effect. If you want to implement protocols after compilation or during tests, check the "Consolidation" section in the documentation for Kernel.defprotocol/2
      lib/encoder.ex:1**

**warning: redefining module Jason.Encoder.Any (current version loaded from /Users/dev/projects/haitracker.com/haitracker-be/_build/dev/lib/jason/ebin/Elixir.Jason.Encoder.Any.beam)
      lib/encoder.ex:1**

with the following encoder

```
defimpl Jason.Encoder, for: Any do
  def encode(%{__struct__: _} = struct, _options) do
    skip_keys =
      case struct.__struct__ do
        Haitracker.User ->
          [
            :local_password_hash,
            :login_status_message
          ]

        # TODO: define skip keys for each model and pass to this function
        _whatever ->
          []
      end

    struct
    |> Map.from_struct()
    |> sanitize_map(skip_keys)
    |> Jason.encode!()
  end

  defp sanitize_map(map, skip_keys) do
    filter = fn {key, val} ->
      cond do
        key in [:__meta__, :__struct__] ->
          false

        is_map(val) ->
          Ecto.assoc_loaded?(val)

        key not in skip_keys ->
          true

        true ->
          false
      end
    end

    map
    |> Enum.filter(filter)
    |> Enum.into(%{})
  end
end
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to encode all of the schemas I have using `Jason` with just single encoder config file so that all of the encoding options are defined at one place.

Comment: Will this help? https://github.com/michalmuskala/jason#use-with-other-libraries

Comment: @denis.peplin actually. No. I have gone through all the `README`

Comment: Requirement is to exclude `__meta__` and `__struct__` fields and if some association is not loaded, we also need to skip these fields. you can call these keys to be global skip keys and values. and I want to exclude few keys per schema/model. i.e local skip_keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You obviously are not allowed to damage the default `Jason` implementation for anything. You should explicitly tell `Jason` how your structs are to be serialized.

Excerpt from the [Jason README](https://github.com/michalmuskala/jason):

> If you need to encode some struct that does not implement the protocol, if you own the struct, you can derive the implementation specifying which fields should be encoded to JSON:
>
> ```
> @derive {Jason.Encoder, only: [....]}
> defstruct # ...
> ```

That said, you are supposed to explicitly specify what fields are to be filtered out using the `@derive` module attribute.

Comment: Problem is I want to exclude Associations dynamically which are not loaded. Otherwise your solution is perfect.

Comment: For that you have basically two options: implement the protocol for `NotLoaded` or filter them _before_ encoding.

Comment: Filtering seems to be the solution. Because if I implement the protocol for NotLoaded, I do have to return something e.g `NotLoaded` etc or nil which Front end devs dont want. They want to have all associations to have object value or skip if these are not loaded

Comment: Well, I personally would go with a specific negotiated unique value for not loaded associations _filtered out on the consumer side_. It’s a responsibility of the frontend to decide what to do with unwanted values. Just filtering them out on the backend breaks consistency.